# SQL Server: Conversion failed when converting time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a column below that has datatype `char(24)` but the data contains a date

I want to convert the data to `datetime` so that I can select the data from the past hour like this:

```
Where CounterDateTime   >= DateAdd(hour, -1, getDate())
```

But I keep getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

even if I convert my `CounterDateTime` to `datetime`. Please help.

Comment: This is my table I want to convert to datetime (currently its char(24)) https://imgur.com/a/TyFob5N

Comment: What is the format of the date in this column and which version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL 2016. Format of the date in this column is 2018-12-31 12:11:17.679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the column to datetime like this:

```
Where CounterDateTime IS NOT NULL AND Cast(RTRIM(LTRIM(CounterDateTime)) as DateTime) >= DateAdd(hour, -1, getDate())
```

this could also work:

```
Where CounterDateTime IS NOT NULL AND CONVERT(datetime, RTRIM(LTRIM(CounterDateTime)), 121) >= DateAdd(hour, -1, getDate())
```

and 1 more:

```
Where CounterDateTime IS NOT NULL AND try_parse(RTRIM(LTRIM(CounterDateTime)) as DateTime using 'en-US') >= DateAdd(hour, -1, getDate())
```

Comment: I do have null values for counterdate time so I think this is why its not working. How do I convert valid/non-null value only?

Comment: I've tried : "Where CounterDateTime IS NOT NULL AND CONVERT(datetime, CounterDateTime, 121) >= DateAdd(hour, -1, getDate())" but it is still giving me Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I'm getting the data directly from SSRS but its being stored as a char.

Comment: If you have tried both solutions and none works then it's possible that 2018-12-31 12:11:17.679 is not the format you are getting

Comment: My ultimate goal is to select the records from the past hour but I can't do that because I have to convert my counterdatetime first to datetime right?

Comment: Right. Try once again with trim() as in my edited answer

Comment: 'TRIM' is not a recognized built-in function name. *facepalm SQl 2016 doesn't have trim?

Comment: Right it's for 2017 version. Give me a few mins.

Comment: Did not work. :( Still getting the character conversion. However, if I copy and paste the content of one of my date like this "select convert(datetime, '2018-12-31 12:11:17.679', 121)" it works. For some reason, even taking out the null values in my CounterDateTime column, it has trouble converting them. But also, I have 90k rows in CounterDateTime, but that should not matter right? I also tried "select top 1 convert(datetime, CounterDateTime, 121)" but it didn't even work.

Comment: Try 1 more, if it fails too then the format is something else.

Comment: AMAZING THIS WORKED! Where CounterDateTime IS NOT NULL AND try_parse(RTRIM(LTRIM(CounterDateTime)) as DateTime using 'en-US') >= DateAdd(hour, -1, getDate()) THANK YOU SO MUCH I've been trying all morning LOL

Comment: Happy New Year :)

Comment: Happy new year to you too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store date/time values as strings.  This can cause a problem.

The next big issue is relying on implicit conversion.  If you have to convert the values, do so explicitly.  So:

```
Where try_convert(datetime, CounterDateTime) >= DateAdd(hour, -1, getDate())
```

You clearly have values that cannot be converted.  You don't know why.  You can find these values using a query:

```
select CounterDateTime
from t
where try_convert(datetime, CounterDateTime) is null and
      CounterDateTime is not null;
```

This will return the non-NULL values that cannot be converted.

Comment: Hello Gordon, yes I do have null values. when I tried your  first query  "where try_convert(datetime, CounterDateTime) >= DateAdd(hour, -1, getDate())" I get an empty table

Comment: @123testing123 . . . Well, you cannot convert the values implicitly then.

Comment: But even if I select non-null values, and convert it to datetime datatype, it is still giving me the conversion error.

Comment: @123testing123 . . . As explained in the answer, the last query shows you the values that cannot be converted.